# How to delete ACM Certificates not used in AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I want to use AWS CLI to automatically delete certificates that are not in use. The ACM Certs do have a flag called "In Use" which I would like to access.

I found a way of [deleting a certain certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/delete-certificate.html). This requires the name of the certificate.

I tried getting the names by this [list functionality](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/list-certificates.html) but this can only access the *status* of a cert and not the "*In Use?*"-Flag.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect a list of all certificates with list-certificates.

This will give you an object you can iterate over and collect certificate arns. You can pass the each arn into [describe-certificates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/describe-certificate.html) which should return you an object  containing the field `InUseBy`, which is an empty list if it's not in use.

If it's empty, you can delete.